# Which would be the most generic solution to implement a asynchronous callback function using SQS or Webclient for a large scale application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, callback, amazon-sqs, asynccallback

I have to implement a callback mechanism in my spring boot application. I am thinking to go with either of below approaches.

1. Implement a call back with SQS queue.
2. Creating a webclient and call an endpoint to get the response.

Could someone please share if we have any other options to have it as most generic solution.